# Excel: If number in column, return cell two spaces over and cell two spaces over and underneath, output to separate file

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure if this is possible with macros or otherwise, but...

If I have a spreadsheet where numbers exist in column B (first entry is at B7) and I want to return all values in column D that line up exactly with it, and one underneath (D7 and D8, in this case).

Is there a way to write this data to a text file using a macro and put them in this format?

```
D7,D8
D14,D15
D21,D22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt. You select all the values in Column B. I operated with a lot of assumptions form your post, like the values that need to be brought over have a corresponding NUMERIC value on Column B:

```
Sub getDataforFile()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim filePath As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'this assigns your selection, everything on Colum B to a Range variable
Set myRange = Selection 

filePath = "C:\Output.txt" 'put your own path
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(filePath)

For Each myCell In myRange

'if the value in Column B is a number and not an empty string
If IsNumeric(myCell.Value) And Not myCell.Value = "" Then     

'write to the text file, first moving two columns over to the right,
'no rows down, concatenating a comma, and then again moving two columns
'right, one row down, all from the original range, on Column B
    objFile.writeline myCell.Offset(0, 2).Value & ", " & myCell.Offset(1, 2).Value

End If

'continue checking each cell in the selection
Next myCell

objFile.Close

Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm. This code makes a lot of sense to me, but for some reason I am getting a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" when I try it out. The debugger points me to this line: `objFile.writeline myCell.Offset(0, 2).Value & ", " & myCell.Offset(1, 2).Value`

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but perhaps adding the Windows Script Host Object Model in the References may help.

Comment: Figured out the issue. My text is in Asian characters, so VBA wasn't picking  it up. Your code works great though, thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad to know it helps. Do you mind marking this as answered?